# How do I track song plays from playlist using HTML5, Jplayer and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html, jplayer

I am building a custom based player which will have access to 3 play lists. The client selects the playlist they want to hear. At the end of the day I need someway of counting how many times each song on that playlist was listened to. Can this be done in HTML5 or do I need to do this in php and MySql. This has to work for both iOS, Ipad,as well as windows and android.

Comment: can you post your current code, a link to a jsFiddle or development site? Where would you like the store the playback statistics? In a cookie? server-side database? client-side HTML App Cache? server-side XML file? server-side plain text file?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this before, and the solution I came up with was having the MP3 files accessed via a PHP file, which registers the request in a database and then fetches the file and serves it (adding headers so the browser recognizes it as an MP3). Something like:

//track the file after you've confirmed it's a valid request (filename passed in URL as

```
?mp3=[mp3 filename]
$logged = track_this($_GET['mp3']); //some tracking function

//now spit it out...

$file_name = "song_name.mp3";
$file = '/path/to/files/'.$_GET['mp3'].'.mp3';

$mm_type="application/octet-stream";

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack"); 
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

print file_get_contents($file);
```

it works pretty well, though you can't track whether they stopped the track part way through (so it's pretty simple metrics)

Comment: The player I am building is iPad compatible so we are using mp4, that is the easy part. Are you saying I dont use an xml playlist but access a mysql database instead?  You lose me at this point, $file= '/path/to/files/'  How do you path a database? Thank you for the help and am sorry to be asking what is perhaps a stupid question but the leap from xml to a database eludes me..

Comment: I seem to have missed this comment, so sorry about the long delay. No, there's no db access happening here. Basically, the .mp3 files themselves are stored in the directory `/path/to/files/` (so, a song might be at: `/path/to/files/good_song.mp3`. Then you have a php file (`serve_song.php`, perhaps) which is passed a `$_GET` variable (`http://mydomain.com/serve_song.php?mp3=good_song`). The script will then go get file (`/path/to/files/good_song.mp3`) and serve it, sending content headers first so that the browser understands that the served code should be interpreted as an mp3